# In Windows will thread be blocked by Process.destroy() until process is destroyed?

Tags: java, process

In Windows will thread be blocked by Process.destroy() until process is destroyed?
Or it will continue execution even if Process is not destroyed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Process.java) would lead me to believe that a call to destroy() will not wait for the process to be destroyed before returning to the caller.

Look at the documentation for the Process.destroyForcibly() which notes that by default it calls destroy() and that the target process might not be terminated immediately and that you can chain to waitFor() if you need to wait for the target process to be terminated.